# Overriding bootstrap styles, not working

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a simple CSS file to make my app look decently, but I have a problem with it

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
<div id="nav">
        <div class='col-sm-6' align="center">
                <h2>Utwórz nową sesje</h2>
                <br><br>
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" aria-label="Search"><br>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#" role="button">Stwórz</a>
            </div>

        <div  class='col-sm-6' align="center">
            <h2>Dołącz do istniejącej sesji</h2>
            <br><br>
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" aria-label="Search"><br>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-ms" href="#" role="button">Dołącz</a>
        </div>

</div>
```

And no matter if I make it

```
#bootstap-overrides  .container-fluid {
    background-color: #3b5998;
}
```

Or

```
.container-fluid {
    background-color: #3b5998;
}
```

or

```
.nav {
    background-color: #3b5998;
}
```

Background is still white, as if bootstrap was overrding it. I'm a beggineer at CSS.

EDIT:

```
@Component({
selector: 'home',
templateUrl: './home.component.css'})
```

The templateUrl field was wrong, so i fixed it. However, now the entire site appears white.

Comment: What are you tring to do? Your pieces of code concern different things, which one you want to change? `.nav {...}` is not going to work just cause you ve no `nav` class... `#nav {...}` is correct.

Comment: Please add a working example.

Comment: I don't see any problem, [check this](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/pdYdRg)

Comment: That's the thing, I don't see any problem either, yet the backgroung color doesn't change

Comment: Maybe the CSS rules you defined in your page are overriding in layout or parent of a partial view or widget. Make sure do not this happening in your page by viewing page source or inspect it in your browser. Also you can see which CSS rule are overriding your rules in inspector of browser.

Answer (score -2):

You Should organize your CSS links like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css"/>
```

First Bootstrap file and then your custom css file

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change the whole class as example '.container-fluid', you could add the tag !important.

e.g.:

```
.container-fluid {
background-color: #3b5998 !important;
}
```

But in most cases it is more recommended to create child elements as you did.
You have to use your 'nav'-element as follows in your css:

```
#nav {
background-color: #3b5998;
}
```

You have to use '#' instead of '.', because you declared it as an ID- not a CLASS-element

Comment: I do not see the reason to upvote this solution. It has to be '#' in this case and nothing else

Comment: Well, adding # didn't change a single thing

Comment: Use this code snippet and it will work:
`#nav {
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ffaf30;
}`
You div element does not have a height. Otherwise you can set a height to your element instead of using overflow